# How can I set up a VLAN to be firewalled from our intranet?

Tags: vlan, private-vlan

I am being tasked with setting up about 15 PCs to be used as digital signage at my job. These PCs are not allowed to be connected to our internal network/intranet. We do have one Mac workstation that will be connected to our intranet.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I need to be able remote into the Mac PC from any workstation in our intranet. From there I need to be able to exchange files with any one of the 15 PCs connected to the Mac. We need the 15 PC assets to be completely isolated and invisible to the rest of the intranet.

My questions are:
What sort of hardware arrangement would I need to achieve this? How should everything be connected?

Do I only need a Layer 3 switch? Are their any particular features in a L3 switch I should be looking for when shopping for one?

Please excuse the diagram. I am not a network professional and I'm not sure if I am asking the right question(s).[image: poor diagram]

EDIT: To clarify, in regards to the PCs attached to the Mac, I am concerned less about security and more about flying under the radar.

Comment: Based on your edit, this questions is off-topic here because all questions about bypassing network security or policies are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure a separate VLAN for your PCs, say VLAN 100.
2. Assign all the PCs ports to this VLAN 100.
3. Configure a subnet for your PCs, say 172.16.0/24
4. Configure your Mac1 port as a 802.1q trunk, so your Mac1 will be connected both to the PCs VLAN 100 and to the Intranet VLAN.
5. Configure a sub interface on Mac1 for VLAN 100 so it also has an IP form the 172.16.0/24 subnet.

If you have an issue configuring VLAN/trunk port on your existing switch, you can use another switch for PCs and use two NICs on your Mac1.

Please note, that unless you explicitly configure your PCs with a default gateway and your Intranet workstations with a static route, there will be no connectivity between the workstations and PCs as desired.

Comment: Step 4 would not be feasible since we're trying to fly under the radar. (Just now added clarification about security in my description) With 2 NICs, you're saying that I could have 1 switch between intranet and Mac, then a second switch between Mac and PCs? I don't mind the PCs being able to reach out to the intranet. But with this setup I could disallow the intranet to see the children nodes of the Mac unless remoting in, correct?

Comment: And lastly, can just about any L3 switch work for this type of setup?

Comment: For this setup, any cheapest L2 switch will do. Go fly under the radar and have an access from PCs to intranet, you also will need a NAT on your Mac1.

Answer (score 0):

That is what firewalls do. You can use a firewall to isolate parts of your network. This is common in large business networks where labs or other network segments must be isolated from the rest of the network. You install the firewall so that the isolated network is on an outside firewall interface.

You could use ACLs in a router or layer-3 switch to block any traffic to or from the network, too. The difference being that the firewall is stateful, but ACLs are stateless (static). A firewall could be configured to allow fine-grained access from your network to the isolated network.

Your drawing where you have a host (MAC connected to both networks actually defeats any security that you are trying to implement. If you are concerned that the 15 PCs could try to compromise your network, the MAC defeats that if it is compromised.